AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'
I am doing a ANN project to build a prediction model on costs through a medical insurance dataset. Here is the code:
def FunctionFindBestParams(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
    

    batch_size_list=[5, 10, 15, 20]
    epoch_list  =   [5, 10, 50, 100]

    import pandas as pd
    SearchResultsData=pd.DataFrame(columns=['TrialNumber', 'Parameters', 'Accuracy'])
    
    TrialNumber=0
    for batch_size_trial in batch_size_list:
        for epochs_trial in epoch_list:
            TrialNumber+=1
            
            model = Sequential()
            model.add(Dense(units=5, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
            model.add(Dense(units=5, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
            model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
            model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
            model.fit(X_train, y_train ,batch_size = batch_size_trial, epochs = epochs_trial, verbose=0)
            MAPE = np.mean(100 * (np.abs(y_test-model.predict(X_test))/y_test))
            
            print(TrialNumber, 'Parameters:','batch_size:', batch_size_trial,'-', 'epochs:',epochs_trial, 'Accuracy:', 100-MAPE)
            
            SearchResultsData=SearchResultsData.concat(pd.DataFrame(data=[[TrialNumber,     str(batch_size_trial)+'-'+str(epochs_trial), 100-MAPE]], 
columns=['TrialNumber', 'Parameters', 'Accuracy'] ))
    return(SearchResultsData)

ResultsData=FunctionFindBestParams(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)

I have already used append() and concat() functions, but none of them are working. Can anyone help me with this problem, please? Thank you very much in advance.

You are using concat in a wrong way. It should be like this pd.concat()

How exactly do I do that for the code I provided?

Ok I will post that as an answer

The issue is that concat is not a DataFrame instance method but a pandas class method. The right way to use it is like this:
SearchResultsData = pd.concat([SearchResultsData, pd.DataFrame(data=[[TrialNumber, str(batch_size_trial)+'-'+str(epochs_trial), 100-MAPE]], columns=['TrialNumber', 'Parameters', 'Accuracy'])], ignore_index=True)

The pd.concat function takes a list or dictionary of DataFrames as input. I also added the ignore_index=True parameter  to avoid keeping the old index values from the concatenated DataFrames.

The code you provided has worked for the problem. Thank you very much in advance Parman M Alizadeh. I appreciate it alot.

@NikeCage675 Glad I could help. You can select it as accepted answer now
